# Country-specific questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I understand that some country-specific questions are currently welcome in Mathematics Educators.  (For example, questions with the [common-core](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-core) tag are specific to the USA.)

But are questions that are specific to countries other than the USA welcome here?  For example, I am thinking of asking a question looking for mathematics textbooks written in Filipino (the language of the Philippines) but am hesitant to ask it, mainly because I may be the only Filipino active on this site.

Comment: I've been searching on my own and I've found some references that are useful.  I feel that I there is almost no chance I'll get additional references by asking the question here, so I won't be asking it in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question you propose seems fine to me. There are questions that I would find too narrow to be suitable for this site, but the one you propose seems good to me.

This is under the assumption that you intend to flesh out the question a bit regarding the type of book you are looking for; to literally ask for (all) textbooks written in some particular language seems a bit unfocused to me.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, I will be making the question more specific.  I'll wait and see what the other members of the community say.

Comment: Agreed. Similar to Money.SE in that even wish a large US membership, we still encourage question specific to other countries, and do well with them.